# What is the function that generates this graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

I have the following coordinates:

```
( 1, 1)
( 2, 1)
( 3, 3)
( 4, 1)
( 5, 3)
( 6, 5)
( 7, 7)
( 8, 1)
( 9, 3)
(10, 5)
(11, 7)
(12, 9)
(13,11)
(14,13)
(15,15)
...
...
etc.
```

basically: the `y` values are all odd numbers in ascending order but they start over from 1 if the next value exceeds the value of `x`.

Here is a graph:
[image]

Comment: This looks like a modified version of the sawtooth function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might observe that $f(2^n)=1$ and $f(2^n+k)=2k+1$ if $0 \le k \lt 2^n$, though you might want to prove it.

So consider whether you can define $k=x-2^{\lfloor \log_2 x \rfloor}$ and so $$f(x)=2x-2^{1+\lfloor \log_2 x \rfloor}+1.$$

Comment: That is the exact function I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

On can observe that $y=2(x-2^k)+1$ in $2^k\leq x<2^{k+1}$ or $k\leq \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}<k+1$
hense $k=\left \lfloor\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}\right \rfloor$

So, the function is :
$$y=2\left(x-2^{\left \lfloor\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}\right \rfloor}\right)+1$$
where $\lfloor \, \rfloor$ is the symbol of the floor function.

Comment: Your function would give e.g. $(4,0)$ instead of $(4,1)$ and $(7,3)$ instead of $(7,7)$.

Comment: You are right. I corrected it.